# Replacing a failed drive - RAID 1

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, raid1, hardware

I have a Dell PowerEdge r310, MS Server 2008, RAID 1 setup.
I had a two drives fail in the RAID 1 - leaving only one drive in a healthy state.

Picture of disk management:
[image]

I changed the primary boot partition to the Windows Server 2008 Secondary Plex option and the server starts and runs fine, but now I need to replace the failed drives.

I purchased two identical drives to the remaining healthy drive. Same size, speed, etc.

This is where I do not know what I am doing --
Can I just hot-swap the bad drives with the new drives, and the RAID will re-build itself.
And how do I know which bay the failed drives are physically located? The indicator led's on all drive bays are green - which I would have thought one would be in an amber or similar color to alert the failure. Being only one drive left, I don't want to pop out the only healthy drive and cause further problems.

Comment: Is the RAID 1 mirror done through a storage card or the OS?

Comment: I added a picture of the disk management settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAID1 usually implies 2 drives in the RAID. From the above picture, it's looking like one of the drives failed, or else you'd have nothing. Try looking at this technet article:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787481(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_7

about working with dynamic disks...